# Edit text in Sign In link

Tags: toplinks, default.xml, text

I am using a custom theme with Luma parent, and I am trying to change the text of the Sign In link (authorization-link-login) at the top. I am able to edit the text of the register link in my default.xml file successfully using

```
 <referenceBlock name="register-link">
        <arguments>
        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Register</argument></arguments>
 </referenceBlock>
```

But if I try

```
 <referenceBlock name="authorization-link-login">
        <arguments>
        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Text</argument></arguments>
 </referenceBlock>
```

the link still reads "Sign In" and has no change.
Is there another way to change the Sign In text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider just using the i18n translations, less complexity, easier maintainability.

app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/i18n/en_US.csv

```
"Sign In","Your Text"
```

Comment: Works and was very simple. Thank you.